# Redirecting Python import error to file

Tags: python, ipython

I get a huge error output in IPython when I import a certain module. I cannot scroll up to the top of this error so I want to re-direct the output to a file. How can I do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I also tried the following, but it didn't work

```
In [1]: logstart -o
Activating auto-logging. Current session state plus future input saved.
Filename       : ipython_log.py
Mode           : rotate
Output logging : True
Raw input log  : False
Timestamping   : False
State          : active
In [2]: import theano
```

... the error...

```
In [3]: logstop
```

I exit IPython and check ipython_log.py and it looks like this

```
# IPython log file

import theano
```

Comment: Doing this at the IPython prompt does not work, i.e, import module_name 2>error.log . Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe @stark, in his comment above, was recommending that you run the script from the command line by typing something like

`./scriptname.py 2>error.log`

which runs the script called `scriptname.py` (you can replace with your actual script's name) and redirects error messages to a file called `error.log`.

If you are not comfortable working from the command line, I *think* you can do the same by running

```
!./scriptname.py 2>error.log
```

from IPython.

Comment: Thanks! I made a script with just "import module_name" and did what you suggested. I have the error in a file now.

Answer (score -1):

You could increase terminal size to infinity.
In Konsole, i have Settings -> Edit current profile -> Scrolling.